# index.xml does not act as the default entry for apache?

Tags: apache, xampp

I need to config my Apache server that shows the content of a index.xml file like a index.html without the need to put it(index.xml) at the end of the URL like this:

> http://localhost/xml/details/13986
>
> instead of
>
> http://localhost/xml/details/13986/index.xml

Currently, if I remove the index.xml from the URL it shows the files list of that folder in the browser and I need to add index.xml to the end of the URL to get the content.

**Note:** I need this because some old code using this URL without index.xml and I can't change it. For some reason, it doesn't work for me on my computer and I need to add this to the URL to get the content.

Do you have any idea about this config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the configuration in apache2.conf

`DirectoryIndex index.html` instead of `DirectoryIndex index.php`

and restart you apache

Comment: In fact not change, I just added index.xml there. I didn't know about this config